# OneToMany association collection is null in Hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, associate

I am developing a simple `Hibernate` application to test an `OneToMany` association. The Entities I use are `Employee` and `Department` which has many `Employees`:

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long departmentId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

...
getters/setters

}

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long employeeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_fk")
    private Department department;

...
getters/setters

}
```

I create some records with:

```
tx.begin();

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
        session.persist(department);

        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Ar", "Mu", "111");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("Va", "Ka", "333");

        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        emp2.setDepartment(department);
        emp3.setDepartment(department);


        session.persist(emp1);
        session.persist(emp2);
        session.persist(emp3);

        Set<Employee> emps = department.getEmployees();
        emps.remove(emp2);
```

However in the last line: `emps.remove(emp2);` I receive a `NullPointerException`, the `emps` Collection is namely `null`. I have tried to change the owner of the association with:

```
 @Entity
    public class Department {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long departmentId;

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="department_fk")
        private Set<Employee> employees;

    ...
    getters/setters

    }

    @Entity
    public class Employee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long employeeId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="department_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private Department department;

    ...
    getters/setters

    }
```

However the result the same. Why is the `Set` of `Employees` not created. What must be changed in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the collection yourself, either in the constructor or by specifying an initial value for the field.

Indeed Hibernate will initialize the collection to an empty collection when you fetch the object from the database. However, when you create the object yourself and persist it, Hibernate will not really touch the object you created, only persist it, so it won't initialize the field for you in that case.

If you want to make sure the field is never null, which I agree is desirable, simply make sure of it yourself, even before persisting.

Comment: You have right. The problem was merely that the collection is not initialized in the Entity! After having done it works. I could not imagine that the problem would be on such a trivial point, I have copied the Entities from a resource and I did not pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a close look at your code:

```
Department department = new Department();
department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
session.persist(department);

Employee emp1 = new Employee("Ar", "Mu", "111");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("Va", "Ka", "333");

emp1.setDepartment(department);
emp2.setDepartment(department);
emp3.setDepartment(department);


session.persist(emp1);
session.persist(emp2);
session.persist(emp3);

Set<Employee> emps = department.getEmployees();
```

You have created `Department`, three `Employees`, set reference to that `Department` for each `Employee` and persisted them.

Set `emps` will be null because after you persisted employees to database, you didn't reload `department`. If you change code like this:

```
....
session.persist(emp3);
department = session.get(Department.class, department.getDepartmentId());

Set<Employee> emps = department.getEmployees();
emps.remove(emp2);
```

You should be fine.

Another point I'd like to mention - your relation between `Department` and `Employees` are `mappedBy` `Department`, which literally means that `Department` is let's say "master" entity and its `Employee` are "slave", or, if you prefer, `Department` takes all responsibilities on maintaining mapping and references. But, in your code I commented above, you put this mapping responsibility on `Employee` entities. You may want to change your code that way:

```
department.add(emp1);
department.add(emp2);
department.add(emp2);

session.persist(department);
```

in order to make `Department` do its job of maintaining mapping and references.